I can not solve this indefinite integral of $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx$. Please help
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}}\,dx$$

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem in order to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.
